# Suddenly having issues with ibus

Tags: arch-linux, input-method, ibus

I was using ibus on Arch Linux (neofetch below for reference) and it was working perfectly - I was able to switch between languages using my keyboard shortcut, and dead keys were working perfectly.

However, suddenly I am having issues:

1. [FIXED] I can't switch language using my keyboard. I can switch by clicking ibus in the i3-bar, and it changes, but when I use my keyboard shortcut (I've tried both Ctrl+Space and Shift+Tab), the small window comes up in the center of the screen, which I can cycle through, however when I release, the language doesn't change to the selected one.

2. Dead keys only work in the terminal, and nowhere else? I can use them as compose keys perfectly fine in the terminal, as well as Emacs (and I'm sure a few other programs), however in Firefox and Discord, for example, they do not work: I use a UK dead key layout, and when I press a dead key (such as '), it simply puts the dead key ´ or ` etc, rather than composing it with my next input, which also means I can't type ' or " by itself, since it will type ´ or ¨.

Is there any reason for it to suddenly stop working like this? And, if so (or if not), any ideas on how to fix this?

I've already tried completely uninstalling ibus (`pacman -R ibus`) and reinstalling it, as well as wiping the config with `dconf reset -f /desktop/ibus/`, however nothing has worked.

EDIT: I have fixed the **first** issue by adding the following lines to my `.xinitrc`, however the second issue remains:

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE=ibus
export XMODIFIERS=@im=ibus
export QT_IM_MODULE=ibus
```

[image]